# php GD create a transparent png image for ean13 bar code

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a transparent png image.this is a ean-13 bar code image that i want transparent in png format.  I'm having trouble creating transparent png. It currently has a white background.

Can anyone point me in the right direction. This is the code so far...

```
  include('./php-barcode.php');

  $font     = './NOTTB___.TTF';

  $fontSize = 16;   // GD1 in px ; GD2 in point
  $marge    = 10;   // between barcode and hri in pixel
  $x        = 80;  // barcode center
  $y        = 80;  // barcode center
  $height   = 50;   // barcode height in 1D ; module size in 2
  $width    = 2;    // barcode height in 1D ; not use in 2D
  $angle    = 0;   // rotation in degrees : nb : non horizontable barcode might not be usable because of pixelisation

  $code     = $codevalue; // barcode, of course ;)
  $type     = $typevalue; // 

  function drawCross($im, $color, $x, $y){
    imageline($im, $x - 10, $y, $x + 10, $y, $color);
    imageline($im, $x, $y- 10, $x, $y + 10, $color);
  }

  $im     = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 150);
  $black  = ImageColorAllocate($im,0x00,0x00,0x00);
  $white  = ImageColorAllocate($im,0xff,0xff,0xff);
  imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 150, 150, $white);

  $data = Barcode::gd($im, $black, $x, $y, $angle, $type, array('code'=>$code), $width, $height);

  if ( isset($font) ){
    $box = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $font, $data['hri']);
    $len = $box[2] - $box[0];
    Barcode::rotate(-$len / 2, ($data['height'] / 2) + $fontSize + $marge, $angle, $xt, $yt);
    imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $angle, $x + $xt, $y + $yt, $black, $font, $data['hri']);
  }

  header('Content-type: image/png');
  imagepng($im);
  imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: "This is my code so far..." - **My** code? https://github.com/jbdemonte/barcode/blob/master/php/sample%20php/sample-gd.php. Should be "I found someone elses code online, adjust it for my needs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `imagecreate` instead of `imagecreatetruecolor`, then add `imagecolortransparent($im,$white)` after allocating the colours.

Comment: thanks it's working but i need a little more assistance of your please make me correct how can i make only text in transparent and bar code in white

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @user3328337... But you should be able to apply what I've given to you to your needs - if necessary, allocate another colour.